# How to send GET data to the same page without loosing the previous GET data that is the URL to my page?

Tags: php, forms, get, submit

I am on page: index.php?page=2 and there is a search form for "crteria" and "term", but every time I submit, it takes me to index.php?criteria=x&term=x instead of index.php?page=2&criteria=x&term=x. So it ignores the page=2. Also I want to submit the criteria and term on the same page I am. Here's the code:

```
<div id="search">
    <form name="search" action="index.php?page=2" method="get">
        <p>Search by:</p>
        <select name="criteria">
            <option>Name</option>
            <option>Last name</option>
            <option>Project name</option>
        </select>
        <br><input type="text" name="tern" placeholder="term">
        <br><button type="submit">Find`enter code here`</button>
        <hr>
    </form>
</div>
```

On the index.php I include the page that the form is on like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 2){
     include 'modules/search.php';
}
```

So when I'm on index.php?page=2 the search.php is providing me with the form that you can see above.
I know, it's a mess, it's my first project. Thank you in advance.

Comment: consider using sessions instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can simply add an input hidden parameter into your form and remove it from action attribute:

```
<form name="search" action="index.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2">
```

In case of more than one parameter or if the parameters could vary, you could add this code into the php that print the form:

```
foreach($_GET as $k => $v){
    $k = addslashes($k); //or a DBMS specific escape function
    $v = addslashes($v); //or a DBMS specific escape function
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='$k' value='$v' />";
}
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: `addslashes` is fairly hopeless in general. It's utterly hopeless in HTML since a slash isn't an HTML escape character!

Comment: Thank you @Quentin I don't need to make the site XSS-proof, for now, but I will have to learn how to do it for future projects.
S.Pini Thanks for the quick answer!